# Formatting a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, data-processing

I have only posted once here before so forgive me if formatting is off. Also I will say this is a school project.

Anyways, I am just learning pandas, data processing, and csv and am creating a catalog. My code is supposed to take a user inputted file and format it by artist, album, title, duration, and genre. My problem is I need to create a function named print_songs that takes the data frame and iterates it through each row calling print_song, and honestly I have no idea where to start. I have put the code I have below. Any help or resources to understanding data processing and pandas is greatly appreciated.

```
    def load_catalog():
        user_input = input("Please upload a file you want to read:")
        user_file = pd.read_csv(user_input)
        return user_file

    print(load_catalog())

    def print_song(Artist, Album, Title, Duration, Genre):
        print("Artist: ")
        print("Album: ")
        print("Title: ")
        print("Duration: ")
        print("Genre: ")

    def print_songs():`
```

Answer (score 1):

In `print_song()` you are accessing the dataframes row and getting each column by using its name as index.

```
def print_song(row):
    print("Artist: " + row["Artist"])
    print("Album: "+ row["Album"])
    print("Title: "+ row["Title"])
    print("Duration: " + row["Duration"])
    print("Genre: " + row["Genre"])
```

In `print_songs()` you are sending each dataframe row to the `print_song()`.

```
def print_songs(user_file):
    for row in user_file.rows:
        print_song(row)
```

Just make sure when accessing like this `row["Genre"]` the column name is correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_songs(your_data_frame):
    for i in range(lenght(your_data_frame):
        print_song(your_data_frame)
```